# Как работают методы анимации jquery?

Tags: jquery

Посмотрел, как работает метод `slideUp()`. Увидел то, что метод уменьшает высоту элемента до нуля, потом задает свойство `display:none`, а потом зачем-то неотображаемому объекту задает прежнюю высоту. Зачем задавать прежнюю высоту, которая была до применения метода?

Например, есть связка методов:

```
$('#red').slideUp().fadeIn();
```

`div#red` - это красный квадрат. 
Я ОЖИДАЛ увидеть то, что отработку f*adeIn(2000)* вообще видно не будет, так как высота нулевая у красного квадрата

Как-то странно отрабатывают методы:

1. Работает метод `slideUp()`. Сначала красный квадрат уменьшается по высоте до нуля, потом у него задается `display:none` и **зачем-то высота восстанавливается такая, какая была ДО применения метода `slideUp()`**.
2. Работает метод `fadeIn()`. Красный квадрат постепенно появляется, имея при этом первоначальную высоту.

Я думал, что, если метод отработал, то все изменения, которые он сделал, остаются. Например, высота остается нулевой. А высота почему-то становится такой, как до применения метода.

Comment: вопрос - "какие у кого есть соображения по поводу того, почему так странно сделали"

Answer (score 2):

Вот именно потому, что следующая анимация может быть не связанна с изменением размеров элемента. Например, как вы правильно заметили, `.fadeIn()`, который меняет только `opacity`.